# Create a mask like DAVIS dataset

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I am testing the dataset DAVIS from [here](https://davischallenge.org/davis2017/code.html) with one of the papers it has. The codes works fine with DAVIS dataset but it does not work for my data. In particular, the code does not accept the mask I create for the images. Does anyone know how to create a mask like in the DAVIS dataset. Is there a recommended way for that? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tools you might find helpful for annotating and generating Ground Truth segmentation masks:

- [Xyonix Vannot - Video Annotation Tool for Object Segmentation](https://www.xyonix.com/blog/vannot-video-annotations-for-segmentation-made-simple)
- [Best image annotation platforms for computer vision (+ an honest review of each)](https://hackernoon.com/the-best-image-annotation-platforms-for-computer-vision-an-honest-review-of-each-dac7f565fea)
- [Playment.io's Video Annotation tool](https://playment.io/video-annotation-tool/)